# ap computer science hw error

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am currently experiencing error with the following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Catapult
{
    ArrayList<Double> distance;

    Catapult()
    {
        ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    public void calcDistance(Integer[][] data)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a < data.length; a++)
        {
            double speed = data[a][0];
            for(int x = 0; x < data[0].length; x++)
              {
                double radian = Math.toRadians(data[0][1 + x]);
                double dist = (speed * speed * Math.sin(2 *radian)) / 9.8; 
                distance.add(dist);
              }
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < distance.size(); x++)
        {
            System.out.println(distance.get(x));
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CatapultTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Integer[][] data = {{20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {25, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {30, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {35, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {40, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {45, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
                           {50, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50}};

       Catapult range = new Catapult();
       range.calcDistance(data);
       range.print();
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run it, I would get java.lang.NullPointerException "Null". This is an assignment that asks to calculate the range of a projectile with different speeds and angles which are stored in the double array **data**. However, the error keeps showing up and it does not let me add **dist** to the array list **distance**.

Comment: Google "how to read stack trace".

Comment: Please spend some time learning how to use the debugger.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest learning how to debug.  Please read [How to be a programmer](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282) and consider that the first part is debugging.  If you can't debug you will have increasing difficulty later on - its better to learn how to do it earlier than later.

Answer (score 5):

```
Catapult() {
    ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
```

This creates a new local variable with the name `distance` that [shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your instance variable `distance`.

Change that code to:

```
Catapult() {
    distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
```

to access the correct `distance` variable. Then it won't be `null` anymore if you try to use it in your code.

And yes, like in the comments suggested, try to learn how to use a Debugger. This is an important tool to find such bugs by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
Catapult()
{
    ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
```

change to

```
Catapult()
{
    distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
```